Error when calling recasepunc.py with subprocess in Flask app: Error in recasepunc: None
I am working on a Flask application that uses the Vosk speech recognition library to transcribe audio into text, then sends that text to the recasepunc.py script for punctuation restoration. The issue I’m encountering is that I get the following error:
Error in recasepunc: None

The error occurs when I try to pass the recognized text from Vosk to the recasepunc.py script via subprocess. The command I am trying to run is:
processed_text = subprocess.check_output(
    'python recasepunc/recasepunc.py predict recasepunc/checkpoint', shell=True, text=True, input=recognized_text)

Where recognized_text is the result from the Vosk recognition, like "hello how are you".
Here’s the full context of the application code:
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer, SetLogLevel
from pydub import AudioSegment
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import subprocess
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def process_audio():
    file = request.files.get('111')
    
    if file:
        try:
            song = AudioSegment.from_file(file)
            SetLogLevel(0)
            FRAME_RATE = 16000
            CHANNELS = 1
            model = Model("model")  
            rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, FRAME_RATE)
            rec.SetWords(True)

            wavv = song.set_channels(CHANNELS)
            wavv = song.set_frame_rate(FRAME_RATE)
            rec.AcceptWaveform(wavv.raw_data)
            result = rec.Result()  

            recognized_text = json.loads(result)["text"]

            try:
                processed_text = subprocess.check_output(
                    'python recasepunc/recasepunc.py predict recasepunc/checkpoint', shell=True, text=True, input=recognized_text)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                processed_text = f"Error in recasepunc: {e.stderr}"

            return jsonify({
                "recognized_text": recognized_text,
                "processed_text": processed_text
            })

        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500

    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "No audio file provided"}), 400

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)

What I’ve tried:

I have confirmed that the command works directly in the terminal:
echo "hello how are you" | python recasepunc/recasepunc.py predict recasepunc/checkpoint

It returns the expected result: "Hello, How are you?".

I tried using subprocess.check_output() as shown, but the output is "Error in recasepunc: None", which doesn’t provide any useful information for troubleshooting.


My Environment:

Python 3.10
vosk 0.3.45
torch 2.2.2
transformers 4.39.3

Could someone help me understand why this error occurs and how I can resolve it?

Unable to reproduce
The audio details are irrelevant, so I just assigned
your example text directly and set a breakpoint before the return.
It shows perfect output from the subprocess:
(Pdb) pp(ret.get_json())
{'processed_text': 'Hello, How are you ?\n',
 'recognized_text': 'hello how are you'}

Notice that you might possibly wish to .rstrip() trailing whitespace.
You are correctly invoking .check_output() and doing utf8 encode / decode.

Design
If your use case involves repeatedly doing small queries,
such as for four words, then creating all those subprocesses
is far more expensive than you desire.
Each one takes several seconds to import modules and then
read (part of) a 1.2 GiB checkpointed model.
Prefer to read the model just once.
Amortize the cost across multiple queries,
using function call rather than forking off a subprocess.

Thanks for your response! It works perfectly when I run the command directly in the terminal. However, when I try to connect it with my React Native app (via Flask), it doesn’t work. I get the Error in recasepunc: None message. The issue seems to arise when the command is invoked via subprocess.check_output() in the Flask route.Is there something specific to how the subprocess is invoked when the request is coming from the React Native app? I’ve already checked permissions and paths, and I’m not sure why it works directly from the command line but fails when called through Flask.

I had a macOS pty connected to the test code when it ran, as you can see from the "pdb" debugger prompt. I usually have a pty available when I do a debug run of flask in one interactive window which shows logging, and then I do some work in another window. If your setup for running flask manages to close stdout or stderr, and thereby interferes with logging, I imagine that could affect the results. As written, the OP code looks correct to me, and it is not a "repeat-by" in that it doesn't reliably reproduce your reported symptom. Debug the child process so you get a detailed stack trace.

Thank you! I tried this code subprocess.check_output(f"echo '{recognized_text}' | /home/k/%%%/%%%%/env310/bin/python /home/k/%%%/%%%%/voice/recasepunc/recasepunc.py predict /home/k/%%%/%%%%/voice/recasepunc/checkpoint",shell=True,text=True)  and it worked. I hope it's stable.

The echo is fine, but it can suffer from effects like quoting, "too long", and embedded newlines. You may find it more convenient to have python write the recognized text to a temp file, and then use a < file redirection to make the subprocess read it.
